# What is the dimension of $f(A)$ if $f:A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is linear and $A$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $k\le n$ and $f:A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}^n$. Obviously, $f(A)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ iff

1. $\forall x,y\in A:\exists z\in A:f(z)=f(x)+f(y)$
2. $\forall x\in A,\alpha\in\mathbb{R}:\exists z\in A:f(z)=\alpha f(x)$

If $f$ is linear and $A$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^k$, $(1.)$ and $(2.)$ are fulfilled. $\color{blue}{\text{Can we weaken these requirements on }f\text{ and }A\text{?}}$

Suppose $A$ has dimension $k'\le k$. What can we say about $\dim f(A)$?

Comment: @Arthur Hence, I've written "$f(A)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the assumption that $f$ is linear you have that dim$f(A)\leq\mathrm{dim}A$. This is because if $u,v\in A$ are linearly dependent then $f(u),f(v)$ will be linearly dependent in $f(A)$: assume $\lambda u+\mu v=0$ then, since $f$ is linear, $\lambda f(u)+\mu f(v)=f(\lambda u+\mu v)=f(0)=0$. However, if $u,v\in A$ are linearly independent then you cannot deduce that $f(u),f(v)$ are linearly independent, for example if one is sent to the zero vector.

If $f$ is a monomorphism, i.e. $f$ is injective, then dim$f(A)=\mathrm{dim}A$. This is because monomorphism sent a linear independent set of vectors in a linear independent set of vectors. In particular a basis of $A$ will be sent to a basis of $f(A)$.

Notice that dim$f(A)=\mathrm{dim}A$ does not imply that $f$ is a monomorphism. For example assume that $\{u_1,...,u_{l},u_{l+1},u_k\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^k$ and  $\{u_1,...,u_{l}\}$ is a basis of $A$. Then you can construct a linear map with the following properties: $\{f(u_1),...,f(u_{l})\}$ is linear independent and $f(u_{l+1})=...=f(u_k)=0$. In this case $f$ is not a monomorphism (provided that $l<k$).

To conclude, I don't think that there is a nice property (other than "$f$ restricted to $A$ is a bijection") that will imply dim$f(A)\leq\mathrm{dim}A$.

Comment: Under which further requirement on $f$ would hold equality?

Comment: I edited to give more details!